# Radial Gradient as a texture

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to make a radial gradient to put a sunburst on this guitar body similar to this:[image]

What I have so far is this node set up:[image]

**EDIT**

So.....according to this reasoning if I set this up like this I should be able to get a blend between black pink and white in a radial pattern which still isn't even close to happening......any other thoughts[image]
Worse still is I did find a clear shot of a sunburst guitar to do a UV projection but its the back and so the s curves are completly ragged and thats not going to get it.......sorry, had to use the answer section because the comments don't seem to have a way to post a picture.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materialshttps://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to give the color ramp something to work on through its "fac" input (using e.g. the "fac" output from your gradient node).

But your example does not have a simple radial gradient, but one that follows the body curve. In that case, it might be easier to make an image with the gradient you want and use UV mapping on the sound board to place the color.

Comment: I tried the Gradient node in both the factor of the colour ramp and the factor of the mix node......very little result and I tried all the different gradient setting, easing, quadratic, radial etc etc.....nada

Comment: Also good luck findng a sound board without all the bits on it

Comment: @DavidOulton You mean that in your model buttons, fingerboard, pickups etc. are all linked to the basic geometry of the sound board (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> on a soundboard vertex selects everything)? As long as they are separate meshes (even in the same object), it's not too difficult to get an UV mapping aplied just to the finger board.

Comment: no I have the sound board as its own piece of geometry, finding a picture without the bits on it to make a UV map is proving to be impossible.

Comment: If you have a drawing program, you make a picture with the colour gradient for the soundboard, and apply that in a separate material to just the soundboard. All the other bits aren't even touched by that material

Answer (score 0):

To position your gradient texture correctly, it will be easier to view it on its own, through an emmision shader, or, if you're using Node Wrangler, by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>-clicking the node. Depending on your UV, you'll probably need map settings in this sort of range:

[image]

One of your problems, at the moment, seems to be that the scale on your mapping node is set to 0.

The 'Radial' gradient might not be what you expect: it's a kind of clock sweep going from light to dark. The 'Spherical' option is the one that varies from the center to the perimeter.