# Let a gradient follow the topography of the mesh

Tags: mesh, color

I know how to apply a simple linear/radial gradient to a mesh but what if I want more control over the gradient, let's say I want it to follow certain regions of a mesh? I posted two examples of what I mean:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Here a linear/radial gradient probably won't give me the desired results. Can I somehow paint a gradient manually or is there a more convenient method?

Comment: It depends on your specific needs, but you may be better using coloured lights with specific fall off values to create the sort of highlights in those images.

Comment: You can certainly assign [different materials to different parts of the mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh) and make the transition smooth by using gradients. Read:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials

Comment: Do you mean you want a 3D procedural texture to 'stick' to a mesh as it's deformed?