# Cycles Gradient between two materials

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, vertex-colors

How do i create gradient between two materials in one mesh? (second screenchot was edited in PS)

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials/10455#10455

Comment: Except those questions and answers didn't have anything to do with vertex paint. I hope that the solution I provided gives some use in that direction.

Comment: @CraigDJones maybe it would be helpful to add your answer to the proposed duplicate as well, so that users have more options.

Comment: I think the title needs to be edited to add 'using Vertex Paint" that way it is more specific to the situation presented in the screen shots. That, and I can't figure out the best way to point them to my answer here except to replicate it again.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option to use the Vertex Paint Blur tool on the border between the white color vertex and the black color vertex. I paint the center area white in vertex paint mode, and then invert and set paint to black (in the header, go to Paint> Set Vertex Color and this will act like a fill). I used Face Select masking to do this without overriding the center white area. 
[image][image]

I then switch tools to the Blur tool and blur the area around the white spot so that it cause a gray area. To deepen it, I subdivide once to force the vertex paint to blend across the changes. I then use this vertex color in the Attribute node (named Col by default) as a factor to mix between a diffuse black shader and a blue emission shader.
[image][image]