# Shader smoothing

Tags: shaders, smooth

I have 1 mesh. I assigned 3 materials to different part of geometry in that mesh by going to Edit mode, selecting some faces and assign material.
Problem: I wanted to smooth shader, but I noticed that only one material looks smoothed. How can I do this? Please, see the screenshot.
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Isn't that a texture?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133739/cycles-gradient-between-two-materials https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49914/smooth-transition-between-two-materials

Comment: Thanks. I did it