Gradient transition between two materials
I have a complex object with two assigned materials. Inner material is white and the outer material is black. I would like to create a gradient transition between the materials, from white to black material. I want to do this without uv mapping, Can I somehow use the data from the edge loop to create the gradient?
The black part would be made by mixing black and white color shaders and creating the transition. Thw white part is just one material.
I used a cylinder just as an example.


for an object as simple as a cylinder you can use the Texture > Gradient node in Spherical mode and then a ColorRamp, but if it's a more complexe object and you want the transition to follow the convexe edges, I don't know if it's possible

Yeah I need it for another object. This is so easily done in Corona with a distance map.

if you are in Cycles you can try these ways: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_wEXl3LncAc or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bxKHAfFWRM

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133739/cycles-gradient-between-two-materials/133743#133743 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials/10455#10455

You can use Attributes with vertex paint:
In Solid Viewport shading, go to edit mode, select the inner circle, then switch to vertex paint mode.
change the Domain to Vertex and the Type to Color, then enable the face mask selection in the top left corner; use a paint brush to fill all selected vertices, so to get a Black and white mask.

Now go to rendered or material preview mode, in the shader editor add an Input > Attribute node, type the exact name of the painted attribute.
The gradient will happen between an edge ring that has a black vertex color and another edge ring which has white.
Use a Color Ramp node to fine tune the effect.

