Shading different parts of a mesh
I’m beginning my journey with shading in Blender and I’m wondering how to assign different shading to the same mesh. For example, when I’m sculpting a creature and I want to shade scales in a different way than the body, how do I do it? I would like to keep the scales and body in the same mesh so they don’t seem separated later. Thanks for the advice.

Sugest you follow one of the many YT tutorials on materials and shading in Blender. I'd suggest starting with this one by Ryan King which shows how to use and add different colours on different parts of a mesh.

Use b&w masks as factors in Mix Shader nodes or in Color Mix nodes that mix 2 shaders or 2 colors or image textures

If you had one specific material setup where you wanted to change something we might be able to help you with it, but as you say for yourself you are just starting your journey with shading in Blender, so I would really recommend watching tutorials on materials, textures etc. like John said, to become familiar with how shading in Blender works in general... because I'm not sure how much experience you already have, if moonboots' tip would help you or if all those words are just meaningless to you at the moment?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials/10455#10455
