# Bringing out text within an Image Texture

Tags: texturing

I've only been using blender a few days and I'd love to be pointed in the right direction on to how to alter the text I have within my image textures
[image: text on labels]

I want to make the text on the labels stand out by maybe making them glossy like the lids whilst still keeping the rest of the label glossy and with the shaders I already have set.
Can I edit this from the image texture or could i maybe add a seperate text layer from the image texture and add on top?? (I haven't explored anything like text yet and I'm pretty lost on what I can do!)

Thanks any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could use a diffuse node (image) and a glossy node, combined by mix shader with mask as factorial

Comment: @FacebFaceb how would i go about adding a mask/whereabouts is the mask option?

Comment: @Libby check out the link suggested by RayMairlot, it has a full explanation of the steps -- if that doesn't help you, let us know.

Comment: @zeffii I've been trying the answer given in that link, I have made a specular but I am in cycles render and those options following aren't visible to me [link](http://imgur.com/8nQddCN)

Comment: check this answer (further down) http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5070/47 (for the cycles specific stuff)

Comment: like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/o4dvT.png

Comment: @zeffii fantastic thank you that's solved it!