# How to make parts of a texture Shiny

Tags: texturing

I have this box and i need to make the yellow parts shinny golden but the text on top of it to be there as it is. Any idea how to do this?  [image]

Answer (score 2):

Make a second texture that is a copy but is black everywhere except white where you want the shiny (gloss) and add that as a texture to influence the specular only in Blender Render material, or to control the amount of gloss node effect in Cycles material.