# Add two Principled BSDF with alpha

Tags: node-editor

I want to add two Principled BSDF in one material to one as texture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe92I.png) and principles for logo only with transparency to control roughness.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't necessarily need two materials, if you just create an uv map for the area where you want the image , then the rest of the object will not have the image as texture. Read: [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46447/1853)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208639 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95522 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5069

Answer (score 5):

[image]

If I understood your question, you have to combine two different materials into one, using the alpha channel to mix between the two shaders.

In my example I created a material for all the faces except the zone of the logo, then duplicated it, assigned the dupli version to the faces of the logo zone, then added in the dupli version a new principled shader, with the image as base color.

Then I used alpha channel to mix between the two shaders.

Comment: OMG, it's working perfectly as I want, thank you so much~