# Two materials on one object - One metallic, One matte

Tags: materials

First, I'm VERY new at this, so please bear with me.

What I'm trying to do is create a label on a bottle that has certain parts that are gold foil and the rest is somewhat matte. This is an actual bottle in real life that needs to be pretty exact. I will also need to make many multiple other bottles of different shapes/sizes, so the technique I use will need to be very efficient.

I started with the image of the label as one material UV unwrapped onto the object (label) and it looks pretty good, but the gold foil parts of the bottle need to look more metallic. And if I do that, it makes the rest of the label metallic looking. I've tried adding the gold foil parts as one image and the rest of the label as another image, but that doesn't work for two reasons: 1. the combined images aren't as sharp as using just one 2. I still can't make the gold foil and matte parts look like two materials.

I've tried every tutorial I can find, but none fit this exact example.

[image]

Comment: Welcome Cody! I suggest create a *matte* (for each shader) and it into the *fac* socket of a *mix shader* node: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/748/31447

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164277/add-two-principled-bsdf-with-aplha/164279#164279

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95522/how-to-make-parts-of-a-texture-shiny https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5069/id-like-to-have-portions-of-a-texture-not-glossy https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90064/using-an-rgb-map-to-assign-various-shaders-in-a-material/90065#90065

Comment: @joshsanfelici that is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Further reading: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/