# How to stack different materials on beer can product label

Tags: materials

I am a graphic designer attempting to make 3d product renders of many beer cans. Each of them has a matte finish art layer with portions masked out to the aluminum can below. In addition, the aluminum also has a color over it like gold to simulate a gold finish, but the rest of the can (top and bottom is still silver aluminum).

I was able to map a gold material to the middle part of the can mesh, so I think I have that part figured out. I saved the label as a png with an alpha, so I figured out how to get it working (to see through the label and reveal the metal behind it, but I have other layers of art that need to go over it. I tried "add node" but "add" mixes the materials 50-50 and it gets transparent and light. I tried mix and I can only see one or the other texture or 50-50.

I need to stack labels on top of each other, (like photoshop layers where the one on top covers the bottom)each with their own alpha channels and material finishes. I have another one with gold foil. One layer might be glossy on some parts of the text. That kind of thing. I'm stumped and the client is hot to trot. I am very new to Blender and probably won't understand unless it's step - by - step. Anyway, thank you to anyone that may have pity on me.

[image: janky version so far]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5069/id-like-to-have-portions-of-a-texture-not-glossy https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90064/using-an-rgb-map-to-assign-various-shaders-in-a-material/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/how-to-place-a-png-texture-with-transparency-over-a-material

Comment: Just to be sure, you're asking how to make the golden metal "shine through" the label? like this here?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIFEg.jpg Mask out the *Metallic* value of the *PrincipledBSDF* and the *Roughness* (inverted mask or use a ColorRamp node).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate b/w mask for the top layers, then use the *Mix RGB* node to mix two layers and use mask as factor. Repeat this with all layers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thank you. That is a good lead. I will look into it and see what I can figure out <3